# How to use address to get the value in a range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to get values from a range by using the address of a range I am looping:

```
Sub func (selections As Range)

   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Range ("A2:AF35")

   For Each cell In rng
      
       If cell.Value < 0 Then
               cell.Value = selections.*current address of cell*.Value
       End If
    Next cell
End sub
```

Is this possible? I'm guessing there are better ways but I'm new to VBA and not very experienced in programming either.

Comment: It's not obvious what you are asking after but code like `ActiveCell.Value`, `Cell.Offset(x,y)`, `Cell.Address` or using a `For i = 0 To selection.Cells.Count` loop to access `selections.Cells(i).Value` may be what you are looking for. You should also Dim all your variables. For example `Dim cell As Range`, `Sub func(selections As Range)`

Comment: What `selections` should be? A Range, like it looks to be? If yes, it is good to properly declare it. Your code is strange. Since you have `If cell.Value < 0 Then`, a second similar condition is useless. Are you sure that you do not want using `If cell2.Value < 0 Then`? If I understand well what you mean, you can replace `selections.*current address of cell*.Value` with `cell2.Address`...

Comment: You're right @FaneDuru, edited. I am trying to revert the value of a cell (rng) in a bigger range by getting the previous value stored in a smaller range within the bigger range (selections). E.g. I have a range full of values, change a multiple selection of these, if a cell gets a invalid value I want to revert it. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does not, on my taste... How do you imagine that you will keep the "previous value stored in a smaller range"? How does your code do that? If 'selections' is a bigger range, not a single cell, what address of it should be the one you need? If you need to revert to a previous value of a changed cell you can simple use `Application.Undo`. If you want memorizing a whole rage values and, in some conditions, to revert of the memorized value for a specific cell, you can do that only using a `Static` or a `Global` `Range` or a `Variant` (array) variable. Your code does not say too much, to get you

Comment: I think you are approaching this wrong.  Please edit the Q to include some sample data, the expected result and an explanation of how the expected outcome relates to the data.

Comment: @FaneDuru. Application.Undo is exactly what I needed. So easy! Thanks